# What is the input file format for the function word2vec from package word2vec?

Tags: python, word2vec

I am trying to do my own word embedding using the package word2vec (https://pypi.org/project/word2vec/). 
However, I can't find the file format of the input file for the function "word2vec".

I tried .txt format and pickle file but neither does work.

For example, where corpus.txt has been made with the Windows Notepad and contains "I am a foo bar corpus test"

```
import word2vec
word2vec.word2vec("corpus.txt", "corpus.bin", size=100, verbose=True)
```

I would have expected:

```
Vocab size: 7
Words in train file: 7
```

as in the example here : https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/danielfrg/word2vec/blob/master/examples/word2vec.ipynb

but got only

```
Vocab size: 1
Words in train file: 0
```

Does anyone knows which type/format of file this function accepts ?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a good chance your specific results are because most word2vec implementations discard all words that appear fewer than some *minimum-count* value, usually 5. (Word2Vec doesn't create good vectors for such rare words, and their presence usually interferes with better vectors for other more-common words, so discarding them is usually a good idea on real-sized corpuses.)

So a toy-sized input file, of just 7 words each appearing once, leaves nothing but (maybe) one synthetic word.

Because that PyPI package appears to be a thin wrapper around the `word2vec.c` code originally released by Google, you could probably refer to [that code](https://github.com/tmikolov/word2vec) to learn more details about formats/usage.

But, you could also use the [`Word2Vec` implementation in the Gensim library](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html) - a far more common choice when using Python, with much more documentation & flexibility.

Comment: Indeed, with larger text - the format .txt is working - thank you ! However, pickle format is still not working properly.

Comment: Glad it's working! As the Python pickled-object formats are specific to Python, it's unlikely that code which thinly-wraps a plain-C word2vec implementation would be able to do anything with Python-pickled-objects.